# Run set of commands as sudo in shell script

Tags: shell, sudo

I want the following in the middle of my shell script .

```
---
sudo -u user1
cp /files ./  (as these files are only accessbile to user1)
exit 
----
continue as me .
```

The problem is that till sudo it runs fine,  the rest of the commands after sudo aren't executed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `sudo` incorrectly.  Try:

```
sudo -u user1 cp /files ./
```

There's no need to split it into two lines (and indeed doing so is wrong).  The "exit" exits your script, so nothing after it is executed.

Comment: aah, i missed that, Thanks !!